# probability: Bernoulli random vector where $X_i$'s all have the same mean and variance

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $\mathbf{X}$ is a Bernoulli random vector where $X_i$'s all have the same mean and variance, is it possible to tell if the $cov(X_i, X_j) = 0$ for $i\neq j$; that is, $X_i$'s are de-correlated?

We know that $E[X_i] = p$ and $var(X_i) = E[X^2] - E^2[X] = pq$.

By definition, 
$$
cov(X_i, X_j) = E[X_iX_j] - E[X_i]E[X_j] = E[X_iX_j] - p^2
$$ 
Can we find out what $E[X_iX_j]$ is with this information?
$$
E[X_iX_j] = \sum_{i,j}x_ix_jp_{X_i,X_j}[x_i,x_j] = 0^2p_{X_i,X_j}[0,0] + 0\cdot 1p_{X_i,X_j}[0,1] + 1\cdot 0 p_{X_i,X_j}[1,0] + 1^2p_{X_i,X_j}[1,1] = p_{X_i,X_j}[1,1]
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a vector of length two where $\Pr(\textbf{X}=(0,0))=\Pr(\textbf{X}=(1,1))=0.5$.

Note $p=0.5$ and $\text{Var}(X_i)=0.25$ and $\text{Cov}(X_1,X_2)=0.5-0.25\neq 0$.